# Random Sort List Definition Error in Flutter/Dart

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

Basically I'm trying to build a simple shuffle on a 2D list, however for some reason it doesn't like the "switch over", the details are below:

```
List <GameCard> deck = [
  GameCard(name : "purple", color : Colors.purple[400],  value : 2, random: 0, delete: 0, key:1),
  GameCard(name : "purple", color : Colors.purple[400], value : 2, random: 0, delete: 0, key:2),
  GameCard(name : "red", color : Colors.redAccent[400], value : 2, random: 0, delete: 0, key:3),
  GameCard(name : "red", color : Colors.redAccent[400], value : 2, random: 0, delete: 0, key:4)];

List <GameCard> temp = [deck[0]];

/*Assign the random variable*/
var rng = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
  deck[i].random =(rng.nextInt(1000));
}

/*Sorting Function*/
for (var a = 0; a < deck.length - 1; a++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < deck.length - 1; b++) {
    temp = deck[b];
    if (deck[b].random > deck[b + 1].random) {
      deck[b] = deck[b + 1];
      deck[b+1]  = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

The lines which error is when it refers to setting **temp to deck[b]** and then later on - it says "Game Card" can't be assigned to list "Game Card" though this doesn't make sense in my head as they are the same type of object.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It might have to do with how you are importing the `GameCard` class file. For whatever reason, Dart treats types retrieved from package imports ("package: package_name/...") and relative imports ("../../package_name/...") as mutually exclusive types. So if you import the same class one way in one file and another way in another file, those types will technically be different and incompatible with each other.

Comment: GameCard is something I create above the code - so shouldn't be this, so odd. The error message makes no sense haha. Nevermind, sorted using dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for some reason just setting the temp variable to dynamic worked, no idea why it wouldn't the original way but helps solve it.